# Stateless and Stateful widget, can i use both?

Tags: flutter, dart, stateless

Is it possible to combine the two widgets?
Now I'm studying flutter and if I want to keep my AppBar fixed or something else. Can I have both widgets? If it's possible, should I use the build widget on both?

I haven't tried it yet because I don't understand when I should use the `build()` function. But I saw that Stateless is when there are no changes in the state of the screen and Stateful when there are changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine both of Stateful and Stateless widget. This is better to control `build()` costs. This is a example: You have a screen with a list of items and quantity for each item. At the trailing of item, you have a button **add more** to increase quantity of item by one.
This is solution for this:

Stateless widget (screen shows list of items)

```
import 'package:demoapp/have_state.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NoState extends StatelessWidget {
  const NoState({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: List.generate(
            5,
            (index) => HaveState(title: 'item $index'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Stateful widget (item hold state itself)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HaveState extends StatefulWidget {
  const HaveState({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
  });

  final String title;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<HaveState> {
  int state = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
      child: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('${widget.title} quantity: ${state.toString()}'),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => setState(() {
                state += 1;
              }),
              child: const Text('add more'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When you click `add more` button, only `HaveState` item will be rebuit, not entire NoState widget. It takes you more controls your `build()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Yes
You can combine both
By Using Stateless as Child of a Stateful or stateless as Parent

eg: The Scaffold Widget is a Stateful that can 'receive' lots of Stateles

The SafeArea widget is a Stateless,and you can set a Stateful widget as child.

Too keep your AppBar fixed just need something like that :

```
Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(

        title: const Text('AppBar'),

      ), //AppBar
)
```